# An integral to solve

Tags: integration

I have some problems trying to solve this integral:

$$
\ \int^\ \frac{(x^2-1)\,dx}{(x^4+3x^2+1)\cdot\arctan\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)^{1001}}\,.
$$
I can see 
$$
(x^2+1)^2+(x)^2=x^4+3x^2+1
$$
So i´m thinking in do some trigonometrical substitution, but
how I can get the $$x^2-1$$
Every answer helps and
sorry for the English.

Answer (score 11):

$$t=\arctan \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)\Rightarrow dt =\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+3x^2+1}\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice that